# WebWorker wrong MIME type during importScript

Tags: javascript, mime, web-worker

I am trying to learn web workers. In my project, when I try to import another script in a worker script I get wrong MIME error.

I am trying to proceed with simplest example.

Here is my scripts

main.js

```
const worker=new Worker("js/myWorker.js");
worker.postMessage();
```

myWorker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

    importScripts('./myModule.js');

})
```

myModule.js

```
console.log("Hi from a module");
```

here is the exception that I get
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8000/js/myModule.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable.

Comment: What server setup are you using?

Comment: I get the same error, and I also suspect that it originates in `importScripts`. I use NGINX, though I doubt that it matters. Just in case, I have correct MIME set for `js` there (`application/javascript`).